# Is the following notation correct for $(af)'=af'$ and is $(af)'$ the same as $(af)'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I want to show that $(af)'=af'$ where $a$ is a constant, i.e. $d(a)=0$ and $f$ is a continuous function, differentiable at $x$. Is the following approach correct? I prefer Leibniz notation.

I don't think that $d(af)=\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{(a*f)(x+h)-(a*f)(x)}{h}}$ because this is the derivative w.r.t. $x$ – $\frac{d(af)}{dx}$, not $d(af)$ – is there a way to make this universal/more general?

$$
\begin{align*}
(af)'=d(af) &= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{(a*f)(x+h)-(a*f)(x)}{h}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{(a*f(x+h))-(a*f(x))}{h}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{a*(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}{a}*\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}\\
&= a*\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}\\
&= a*f'(x).
\end{align*}
$$

I seem to have to use $\frac{d(af)}{dx}$, not just $d(af)$. First, is the above correct, and second, is there a way to show this for $d(af)$ more generally (or why is the above sufficient)? I'm not too familiar with math notation.

Edit:

I think I'm actually confused by the difference between $(af)'$ and $(af)'(x)$ – or $d(af)$ and $\frac{d(af)}{dx}$. Are these two the same? They sometimes seem to be used interchangeably.

Comment: It is probably too confusing to use $d(af)$ to mean the derivative of $af$.  As you noted, the derivative is written $\frac{d(af(x))}{dx}$

Comment: Isn't $d(.)$ how one notes the total derivative though, and isn't that what $(af)'$ means? Even though that's just for multivariable functions? Otherwise, wouldn't it have to be $(af)'(x)$ instead of just $(af)'$? Or are these two the same? @GEdgar

Comment: If I recall correctly, $d(\cdot)$ refers to the differential, not the derivative.

Comment: @soupless I've amended my question; I think I'm confused by these two.

Comment: While the "differential" *is* the derivative in multivariable calc, you would do well not to use Leibniz notation $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm d x}$ and the notation $\mathrm df$ at the same time. Even worse, you're mixing it with Lagrange notation $f'$. Pick one of them and stick with it, otherwise you'll just confuse yourself.

Comment: Okay – thank you – so what would be the difference between $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $df$ in this case? @Vercassivelaunos

Comment: There is no difference. That's the point. They mean the same thing, but expressed using different notations. *Don't* express the same thing in different notations unless you're already very familiar with the subject.